# informatica issue with host name

Tags: information-retrieval, informatica, informatica-powercenter

The informatica server is configured on windows 8 system . Now the domain database connection got changed. I mean the port number was changed due to some issue. Now the infa services fails to start up . Please let me know how to change the configuration now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the infasetup.bat command to update connectivity information for domain configuration database.

Switch to the directory where Informatica server is installed (Ex.C:\Informatica\9.5.1\server). Then run the below command with database details

`infasetup.bat UpdateGatewayNode -da  database_hostname:database_port -du database_user_name -dp database_password -dt oracle -ds database_service_name -dn domain_name`

OR

`infasetup.bat UpdateGatewayNode -ds "jdbc:informatica:oracle://host_name:port;SID=sid" -du database_user_name -dp database_password -dt oracle -dn domain_name`